# SharePoint Cascading drop down / jquery select/ auto fill

Tags: 2007, spservices

I've got a cascading dropdown question. I'm trying to accomplish this with using 
[SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation) , but I'm running into difficulty when two of the fields should just auto populate.
Here's an example:

```
App:                 User:                    Admin:                   level:
x                     bob                      joe                      3,8,9
y                     carol                    anna                     2,3,1
j                     frank                    lynn                     7,9,0
```

so, if the user selects: "x" it should auto populate "bob" and "joe"..... level will stay a selector.

Any help??  Should I go about this totally different?

Here's an example of how it should work, but with fields from a sharepoint list :  [Example](http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tutorial002.html)

Here is the script that I'm currently using.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../../../SiteCollectionDocuments/jquery.SPServices-0.5.8.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
            relationshipList: "Business_Owners",
            relationshipListParentColumn: "Apps",
            relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
            parentColumn: "Application",
            childColumn: "Business Owner",
            debug: true
        });

      $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
         relationshipList: "Security_Admins",
         relationshipListParentColumn: "Application",
         relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
         parentColumn: "Application",
         childColumn: "Security Admin",
         debug: true
      });

          $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
         relationshipList: "Security_Level",
         relationshipListParentColumn: "Application",
         relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
         parentColumn: "Application",
         childColumn: "Security Level",
         debug: true
      });


    });
</script>
```

I tried applying this [HERE](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2010/08/26/sharepoint-extending-the-dvwp-%e2%80%93-part-31-filling-in-default-data-on-the-insert-template-with-jquery/) with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the cascade drop downs is what you want in this case. Cascade drop downs just filters available choices and is a bridge between missing OOTB Sharepoint features and InfoPath.

I'd tackle it with a function that calls GetListItems to fetch the data from the list since you aren't looking to really filter the data choices, but populate existing fields based off a selection in another field.

Here's a snippet that I'm using to prepopulate a field (on presave). You could bind it to a blur or onchange function of your initial drop down list.

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Labs",
    CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Lab_x0020_Location'/><Value Type='Text'>" + $("input[title$='Lab']").val() + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName='z:row']").each(function() {
   $("input[title='Lab ID']").val($(this).attr("ows_LabID"));
    }); //close each
  } //close complete
}); //close SPServices
```

Answer (score 0):

have you looked through the SPService documentation, and through the discussion threads? what you describe seems straight forward. put together a sample of the code, and then we can walk you through it.
[spservice cascading dropdown](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation)

Jason

Comment: SPService documentation was the first place I looked.

Comment: are you adding this in a CEWP? Where are you adding the references to jQuery and SPServices? What errors are you getting?